# Collapsing Tree not working

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to create a collapsing tree and was able to find the answer here.

However, when I click on the folder, it doe not collapse and I am not sure why the second item does not appear.

```js
$('.folder').on('click', function(e) {
    var folder = $(this).find('.sub-folder');
     if (e.target !== this) return;
   
     if(folder.hasClass('hidden1')) {
    folder.removeClass('hidden1');
     } else {
    folder.addClass('hidden1');
     }
 });
```

```css
.folder {
    cursor: pointer;
 }
 .sub-folder{
  cursor:pointer; 
 }
```

```html
<ul class="container" style="list-style:none; margin-left:-14px">
                    <li class="folder">
                         <h4><a href="#" ><img src="images/folder-documents-icon32.jpg" alt="Custodial" class="float-left"/ >&nbsp;Disease Management</a></h4>
                            <ul class="sub-folder hidden1" style="list-style:none">
                             <li>
                                 <h5><a href="DMgmt.cfm"><img src="images/folder-documents-icon32.jpg" alt="Custodial" class="float-left"/ >&nbsp;Disease Management</a></h5>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                       </li> 
                   </ul>
```

**UPDATE**

The following i the toggle and it does not work out for me:

```js
var toggle = function () {

        $(this).parent().children().toggle();
        $(this).toggle();

    };

$(".Collapsable").click(toggle);
$(".Collapsable").each(toggle);
 });
```

```html
<ul style="list-style:none; margin-left:-14px">
                    <li class="Collapsable">
                         <h4><a href="#" ><img src="images/folder-documents-icon32.jpg" alt="Custodial" class="float-left"/ >&nbsp;Disease Management</a></h4>
                            <ul style="list-style:none">
                             <li class="Collaposable" >
                                 <h5><a href="DMgmt.cfm"><img src="images/folder-documents-icon32.jpg" alt="Custodial" class="float-left"/ >&nbsp;Disease Management</a></h5>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                       </li> 
                   </ul>
```

and shows the following image:

[image]

However, it appears the hidden folder already. Not when the user clicks on the button and then the second files appears

**UPDATE 2**

Below is what I and it still does not show the hidden link

```js
// JavaScript Document$('.folder').on('click', function(e) {
$(document).on('click', '.folder', function(){
  var folder = $(this).find('.sub-folder');
  folder.toggleClass('hidden1');
});
```

```css
.folder {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.sub-folder {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hidden1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="images/styleregal.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/Collaposable_tree.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="container" style="list-style:none; margin-left:-14px">
                    <li class="folder">
                         <h4><a href="#" ><img src="images/folder-documents-icon32.jpg" alt="Custodial" class="float-left"/ >&nbsp;Disease Management</a></h4>
                            <ul class="sub-folder hidden1" style="list-style:none">
                             <li class="Collapsable" >
                                 <h5><a href="CalMediConnect_DMgmt.cfm"><img src="images/folder-documents-icon32.jpg" alt="Custodial" class="float-left"/ >&nbsp;Disease Management</a></h5>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                       </li> 
                   </ul>
```

Comment: Just use `toggleClass` instead and be done with it.

Comment: I have also tried that and it does not work either. I will post what I did with toggle as well

Comment: You don't have a CSS attribute telling `hidden1` to `display: none;` That is why it shows up at the start

Comment: @Adjit Sorry I do and it still appears. I forgot to add it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are over complicating this. You don't need any of those `if` statements. The point of `jQuery` is to simplify all of this and instead just use something like `.toggleClass()` instead of an `if-else`.

Also, it seems like you do not have a CSS attribute telling any element with the class `hidden1` to be hidden.

See the edits below and it should work as desired.

```js
$('.folder').on('click', function(e) {
  var folder = $(this).find('.sub-folder');
  folder.toggleClass('hidden1');
});
```

```css
.folder {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.sub-folder {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hidden1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="container" style="list-style:none; margin-left:-14px">
  <li class="folder">
    <h4><a href="#" ><img src="images/folder-documents-icon32.jpg" alt="Custodial" class="float-left"/ >&nbsp;Disease Management</a></h4>
    <ul class="sub-folder hidden1" style="list-style:none">
      <li>
        <h5><a href="DMgmt.cfm"><img src="images/folder-documents-icon32.jpg" alt="Custodial" class="float-left"/ >&nbsp;Disease Management</a></h5>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I did exactly what you did and yet it does hide the second folder but once I click the file, the second file doesnt appear? Am I using the wrong script for jquery?

Comment: I even wrote the script and the styling on the html page to see if works and yet it still didnt work

Comment: @RobertoFlores and you are referencing the `jQuery` library as well? Because it should work.

Comment: I am that is why I am confused

Comment: Nope. Hmmm I will send you want I did. Maybe I am calling the file wrong

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have posted what I did

Comment: @RobertoFlores maybe load in your script after the `jQuery` library

Comment: Did that this morning and no result

Comment: You should put those in your `<head>` tags anyway. But other than that, it should work. It even works in the snippet here.

Comment: I know Adjit. It is annoying that it isn't working and yes, the scripts are within the head tags. I know right, it works here but not in my end.

Comment: Is their another approach to this? I have tried other means that I found in stackoverflow and they dont work on my end

Comment: Well I cleared the cache and closed and reopen a new browser and it works to be working. Not sure why, but not going to question it. Thank  you for your help Adjit